# Preprocessor to include file

Tags: ruby, command-line, gsub

What's a simple way to implement file inclusion in Ruby, e.g. if a text file includes {{{stuff.txt}}}, the contents of stuff.txt is included in-line. I thought maybe something like this:

```
cat prog | ruby -pe 'gsub /{{{.+}}}/, File.open("$0").read'
```

... with eval() involved, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to do it straight from the command line, try

```
cat prog | ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/{{{(.+?)}}}/) { File.read $1 }'
```

As pointed out by Alex D, `.+` is greedy and matches as many characters as it can. On the other hand, `.+?` tries to match as *few* characters as possible.

Ruby's command line `-p` expects you to update the value of the `$_` variable. Hence usage of mutating `gsub!` instead of `gsub`, which makes a copy. The same result could be achieved by using `-n`.

```
cat prog |  ruby -ne 'puts $_.gsub(/{{{(.+?)}}}/) {  File.read $1 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.gsub(/{{{(.+?)}}}/) { |m| File.read($1) }
```

A couple points:

- There is an important difference between .+ and .+?. Using .+, it is easy to make regexps which eat too many characters.
- You need to use a block to calculate the replacement (since it is dynamic)

Comment: Also, inside the block you may use $0 and $1 global variable:
`s.gsub(/\{\{\{(.+?)\}\}\}) { File.read($1) }` (note that I added grouping to the regex)

Comment: Mind that '{' and '}' aren't special characters in Ruby's regular expressions. `'{a}' =~ /{a}/ # => 0`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these issues out.
BTW I did find the {{{ }}} work without backslashes.